# Is method/property chaining a good practice?

Tags: c#, methods, method-chaining

I just have a quick question to ask. Is this bad programming practice or is this ok?

Right now I have something like this:

```
TestClass testClass = ClassSelectorTool.Selector.SelectedClasses.ElementAt(index)
```

As you can see. It takes multiple calls to get the value I would like. Is there a better way of going about this? Or is this ok?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you identify some _specific_ harm that the above code is causing to your program? If so, then you should ask a _specific_ question about how to avoid that harm. If not, then I think you have already answered your own question yourself.

Comment: This is called "method chaining" and it is very subjective / opinion based.  It is not generally the kind of question that will get a good answer on this site.  Another way to do it (if you don't like it) would be to assign the results of some method calls to a variable and use that variable to invoke additional methods.  Personally I would decide based on how many times I needed to reference `SelectedClasses`, if I just needed it once I would use method chaining, otherwise I would assign it to a variable.

Comment: @VincentUgenti Yes that's the name! I completely drew a blank and didn't remember what it was called. But wouldn't it more appropriately be called Property chaining?

Answer (score 3):

Method chaining? But there's only one method.

It's a strong indicator of bad design when you have to reach out across your object graph with long chains of properties so that you can find what you're looking for. You are violating encapsulation by requiring such an intimate knowledge of the inner workings of your `ClassSelectorTool`.

Why not make a property on `ClassSelectorTool` that hides this complexity from the user of the class?

```
class ClassSelectorTool
{
    //............
    public IEnumerable<Foo> SelectedClasses
    {
        get
        {
            return Selector.SelectedClasses;
        }
    }
}
```

So now:

```
ClassSelectorTool.SelectedClasses.ElementAt(index);
```

Now the user of this class doesn't need to know about the implementation details of getting the selected classes (i.e. it's dealt with by a selector object).

Less noise.

Easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's good as long as any of property in your chain is not null, otherwise you'll get a null reference exception.